# Works with jquery arrays, how to compare and remove not unique elements in arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare

I have two arrays consist of JSON

```
array1 = [
            object[0] { Lattitude: 55.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 52.4043} 

            object[1] { Lattitude: 54.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.4043 }

            object[n] ......
          ]


array2 = [
            object[0] { Lattitude: 55.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 52.4043}

             object[1] { Lattitude: 54.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.4043 }

            object[2] { Lattitude: 54.7277775
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.7743 }
            object[n] ......
          ]
```

1) How to compare two arrays and get only unique elements from array2 and return in resultArray ?  - I want to get result like this

```
resultArray =  [ object[0] { Lattitude: 54.7277775
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.7743 }
                  object[n] ......
                ]
```

2) How to compare two arrays and get all unique elements from array1 and array2 ? - I want to get result like this

```
resultArray = object[0] { Lattitude: 55.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 52.4043}
            object[1] { Lattitude: 54.7181815
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.4043 }

            object[2] { Lattitude: 54.7277775
                      Location: 0
                      Longitude: 51.7743 }
            object[n] ......
          ]


function objDiff(array1, array2) {
    var resultArray = [];

    array2.forEach(function (destObj) {
        var check = array1.some(function (origObj) {
            if (origObj.Lattitude == destObj.Lattitude) array1.splice($.inArray(destObj, array1), 1);
        });
        if (!check) {
            destObj.desc = 'missing in source';
            resultArray.push(destObj);
        }
    });

    array1.forEach(function (origObj) {
        var check = array2.some(function (destObj) {
            if (origObj.Lattitude == destObj.Lattitude) array2.splice($.inArray(origObj, array2), 1);
        });
        if (!check) {
            origObj.desc = 'missing in destination';
            resultArray.push(origObj);
        }
    });

    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: You provided code but didn't say what the problem  is with it. Don't you want to compare all properties? Will decimal lengths always be the same for matches? Providing useable data would also help for anyone to test this. Create a demo with sample data

Answer (score 0):

First, What you posted is not valid JSON. If this is a portion of your actual code you need to work on your JSON output. You can plug it into http://jsonlint.com/ for validation. If it's not your actual code then posting some of the actual JSON code would be helpful.

to get the distinct elements of an array you can use jQuery unique()

```
var unique = $.unique(array2);
```

to combine 2 arrays you can use jQuery merge();

```
var all = $.merge(array1, array2);
```

to get the distinct values from 2 arrays just combine the two:

```
var uniqueAll = $.unique($.merge(array1, array2));
```

Comment: thanks a lot Gregg, i know that my JSON array that i wrote is not valid and i'll just try to discribe my example

Comment: and i have last quetion

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouajw3k0/) and the code. This variant is vanilla JS it not contains external libraries ie: jQuery:

```
arr1 = [
    {Lattitude: 'a1', Location: 'a2', Longitude: 'a3'},
    {Lattitude: 'b1', Location: 'b2', Longitude: 'b3'},
    {Lattitude: 'c1', Location: 'c2', Longitude: 'c3'}
];

arr2 = [
    {Lattitude: 'b1', Location: 'b2', Longitude: 'b3'},
    {Lattitude: 'c1', Location: 'c2', Longitude: 'c3'},
    {Lattitude: 'e1', Location: 'e2', Longitude: 'e3'}
];

var uniq1 = uniqueDiff1(arr1, arr2)
var uniq2 = uniqueDiff2(arr1, arr2);

console.log(uniq1);
console.log(uniq2);

/**
 * Returns with an array of all unique coordinate objects from
 * 'array2'
 */
function uniqueDiff1(array1, array2){
    return array1.filter(function (el) {
        return indexOfObject(array2, el) < 0;
    });
}

/**
 * Returns with an array of all unique coordinate objects from
 * 'array1' and 'array2'
 */
function uniqueDiff2(array1, array2){
    var unique1 = array1.filter(function (el) {
        return indexOfObject(array2, el) < 0;
    });
    var unique2 = array2.filter(function (el) {
        return indexOfObject(array1, el) < 0;
    });
    return unique1.concat(unique2);
}

/**
 * Returns with the position of the 'obj' element in
 * 'array' array. If 'array' not contains 'obj'
 * it return -1.
 */
function indexOfObject(array, obj){
    var i = 0,
        pos = -1;
    while(pos === -1 && i<array.length){
        if(compareCoordinates(array[i], obj)){
            pos = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return pos;
}

/**
 * Are the two coordinates equal?
 * Two coordinates are only equal if all of their
 * attributes are equal.
 */
function compareCoordinates(obj1, obj2){
    if(obj1.Lattitude === obj2.Lattitude
        && obj1.Location === obj2.Location
        && obj1.Longitude === obj2.Longitude){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Basically, you have to implement a function which compare your objects, and because of the nature of the object you will need a implementation of the indexOf method which can used by objects.

function uniqueDiff1 is answer for your question #1 and function uniqueDiff2 is answer you question #2.

https://jsfiddle.net/ouajw3k0/